# Populate in redshift the same entry with two csv

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Example:

Csv 1: key, d1, d2, d3

Csv 2: key, d4, d5

Expected on redshift: key, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5

Is this possible? In case you know how to do it tell me but my primary concern is if it is possible to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct copy like this is not possible, you have the following options:

1) Use Redshift Spectrum service - create external schema and query it with a join to get the desired data structure in Redshift. The downside is that it's a pay per run service.

2) Process CSVs with Python or Athena to combine them into the desired data structure and then COPY it.

3) Import them separately into two staging tables and then join into the final table. The downside is that if your data is big it might be problematic to reserve 2x space (one for staging tables, another for resulting table) but you can simply create a view with join.

Comment: Thanks, im trying to avoid the second one and trying to do the 3rd. Now that i know i ll look a bit into spectrum service.

Answer (score 0):

Directly, no, but you could either join the objects in your original ETL process, or use a staging table in Redshift, before then materialising it and dropping the staging tables.

Comment: Thanks i think i can figure out how to it now, basically i was wondering if i could avoid going through an entire ETL process just to do that, and solve it on the redshift side. This way i dont have to move the data to EMR in order to do the inner join and load it later.

Comment: Just do a join in redshift, create a new, joined, output table, and then feed that into EMR